# Newborn Permission to Stay in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

I am on a Tier 2 Visa working in the UK, my wife and two kids are on the Tier 2 dependant visas.

We had a new baby 3 weeks ago and we got her passport, and want to travel outside the UK.
How I will apply for permission to stay for my baby?

Comment: Why wouldn’t you just apply for a Dependent visa?

Comment: Please don't type using all capital letters. It's hard to read, and seems like shouting.

Answer (score 1):

Your new child should [apply for a tier 2 dependent visa](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/child):

> ## Apply as a child
>
> ...
>
> ### You were born in the UK
>
> You’ll get the same permission to stay as your parent if you were born in the UK.
>
> #### If you’re under 18
>
> You can either:
>
> - be added to your parent’s next application as a dependant
> - apply separately
>
> To apply separately, you’ll need to know what kind of permission to stay in the UK (‘limited leave to remain’) your parent has.

If you leave the UK before doing this, she'll need to apply for a visa before she can return to the UK.